# PDO multiple statements in one query-call ends in error with "unbuffered queries"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to implement some nested set operations in PHP/PDO for MySQL. After making an insert operation (like stated here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) I am unable to execute another query because of error HY000/2014:

> Cannot execute queries while other
>   unbuffered queries are active. 
>   Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). 
>   Alternatively, if your code is only
>   ever going to run against mysql, you
>   may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
>   attribute.

The code wich produces the error (the error is thrown at the last "SELECT * FROM tree" at the bottom of the code):

```
// insert a node into a nested set as child
$queryParts = array(
    'LOCK TABLE tree WRITE',
    'SELECT @myLeft:= lft FROM tree WHERE id = :parentuid',
    'UPDATE tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft',
    'UPDATE tree SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft',
    'UPDATE tree SET lft = @myLeft + 1, rgt = @myLeft + 2 WHERE id = :childuid',
    'UNLOCK TABLES',
);

$parentuid = $parent->getUid();
$childuid = $node->getUid();

$stmt = self::$connection->prepare(join(";\n", $queryParts) . ';') or die (print_r(self::$connection->errorCode(),1));
$stmt->bindParam(':parentuid', $parentuid);
$stmt->bindParam(':childuid', $childuid);

$res = $stmt->execute() or die (print_r($stmt->errorCode(),1));

// that does not help :(
if ($res) {
    do {
        $stmt->fetchAll(); // empty array
        $stmt->closeCursor();
    } while($stmt->nextRowset());
}

// is not executed
$rset = self::$connection->query('SELECT * FROM tree')
     or die (print_r(self::$connection->errorInfo(),1)); // that kills the code
while($row = $rset->fetchObject()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

In my opinion there is no open query. **How to solve this error?** Currently I am stucked, so any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Btw: $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true); did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active" occurs if the query contains multiple statements separated by a semicolon and is executed in unbuffered mode.

Solution would be:

- execute each query part separately, each part should be a single query without semicolon ";"
- or switch to buffered mode.